# A hard-Lefschetz theorem with torsion coefficients?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, vanishing-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$. Let $\ell$ be a prime distinct from the characteristic.

Assume we have a Lefschetz pencil of hyperplane sections on $X$. Let $X_{u}=H_{u}\cap X$ be a smooth hyperplane section.

By the hard-Lefschetz theorem for $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-coefficients, we have

$$
H^{1}(X_{u}, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})=H^{1}(X, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})\oplus \mathrm{Ev}(X_{u})
$$

where $\mathrm{Ev}(X_{u})$ is the space generated by the vanishing cycles. The question is, do we also have a mod-$\ell$ decomposition
$$
H^{1}(X_{u}, \mu_{\ell})=H^{1}(X, \mu_{\ell})\oplus \mathrm{Ev}^{\ell}(X_{u})
$$

where $\mathrm{Ev}^{\ell}(X_{u})$ is the space of mod-$\ell$ vanishing cycles?